# Load External Script From Advertising Partner in React.js app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ads, external-script

I want to include two types of ads into my React.js Web app

```
<script async="async" data-cfasync="false" src="//somewebstite.com/invoke.js"></script>
<div id="container-4foobarbaz"></div>
```

and this ad as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
atOptions = {
    'key' : 'somekey',
    'format' : 'iframe',
    'height' : 250,
    'width' : 300,
    'params' : {}
};
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.cdnwebsite.com/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

How Can I include this in my React App? 
I have tried a few things but none have them have worked including:

```
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.async = true;
    script["data-cfasync"] = true;
    script.src = "//somewebstite.com/invoke.js"

    this.div.appendChild(script);
```

and this in the render:

```
<div id="container-4foobarbaz" ref={el => (this.div = el)} >

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example code. The idea behind this is to import ads script when the component is mounted and initialize the ads. Every time the component remount to the DOM, it won't import the already imported ads script. I also create an example for you on Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/example-react-google-ads-0b700

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // inject some code to head element
    const head = document.querySelector("head");
    // import google ads script if not yet imported
    if (!head.querySelector("#my-google-ads-1")) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.id = "my-google-ads-1";
      script.async = true;
      script.src = "https://www.google.com/adsense/search/ads.js";
      head.appendChild(script);
    }
    // add another script to head element
    if (!head.querySelector("#my-google-ads-2")) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.id = "my-google-ads-2";
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.charset = "utf-8";
      script.innerHTML = `
        (function(g,o){g[o]=g[o]||function(){(g[o]['q']=g[o]['q']||[]).push(
        arguments)},g[o]['t']=1*new Date})(window,'_googCsa');
      `;
      head.appendChild(script);
    }

    // init ads
    var pageOptions = {
      "pubId": "pub-9616389000213823", // Make sure this the correct client ID!
      "query": "hotels",
      "adPage": 1
    };

    var adblock1 = {
      "container": "afscontainer1",
      "width": "700",
      "number": 2
    };

    window._googCsa('ads', pageOptions, adblock1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello React.js</h1>
        <h2>These are sample ads</h2>
        <div id='afscontainer1'></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: what If I am using a provider other than google? My provider is Adsterra. What would be the equivalent be of the following call   `window._googCsa('ads', pageOptions, adblock1);`

Comment: You can check the documents on the provider website and adapt my sample code to yours. Normally all providers require us to import libs and initialize ads.

Answer (score 5):

I saw you're trying to use adsTerra, so here is a working example (in Typecript)

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
export default function Banner(): JSX.Element {
    const banner = useRef<HTMLDivElement>()

    const atOptions = {
        key: 'YOUR_KEY',
        format: 'iframe',
        height: 50,
        width: 320,
        params: {},
    }
    useEffect(() => {
    if (!banner.current.firstChild) {
        const conf = document.createElement('script')
        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.type = 'text/javascript'
        script.src = `//www.highperformancedformats.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js`
        conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)}`

        if (banner.current) {
            banner.current.append(conf)
            banner.current.append(script)
        }
    }
}, [])

    return <div ref={banner}></div>
}
```

Comment: It works with only one banner, not mutliple. Could you please explain how to create multiple banner on same page?

Comment: i find the console error VM3508 invoke.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document')
    at VM3508 invoke.js:1:24549 but the website still works well

Comment: @BurakIbis Here's a working solution with multiple banners on the same page (I've validated myself in prod): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823206/adsterra-banner-dont-show-twice-am-i-doing-something-wrong/75583698#75583698

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lots @Bruno Lobo. I try to implement adsterra Native Banner,multi-bammer and it work for me. Some code like below...

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

page...
    
    const Banner()=>{
        const banner = useRef(HTMLDivElement)
    
        
        useEffect(() => {
        if (!banner.current.firstChild) {
            const script = document.createElement('script')
            script.type = 'text/javascript'
            script.src =`//paltryheadline.com/{provideByadsterra}/invoke.js`
    
            if (banner.current) {
                banner.current.append(script)
            }
        }
    }, [])
    
        return (<>
         <div ref={banner}></div>
         <div id=`container-{provideByadsterra}`></div>
        </>)
    }
...

return(
...
<Banner/>
...
)
```

i find the console error

> VM3508 invoke.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'document') at VM3508 invoke.js:1:24549

but the website still works well