# Loading an External Script From AD Partner in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ads

I tried implementing an ad banner to my react website but I'm having some trouble rendering it since its all within a script tag.

I tried doing it that way:

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
  <script type="text/javascript">
  atOptions = {
      'key' : '2b47258bf05eeeee270c27002378ce03',
      'format' : 'iframe',
      'height' : 250,
      'width' : 300,
      'params' : {}
  };
  document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.variouscreativeformats.com/2b47258bf05eeeee270c27002378ce03/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
  ` }} />
```

but the banner didn't render on the website (the code shows up in the inspector).

Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: Duplicate. You can find the solution on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69365070/10890924