# AdsTerra Banner don't show twice am I doing something wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ads

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function AdComponent() {
  const banner = useRef();

  const atOptions = {
    key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    format: "iframe",
    height: 90,
    width: 728,
  };

      useEffect(() => {
        if (!banner.current.firstChild) {
          const conf = document.createElement("script");
          const script = document.createElement("script");
          script.type = "text/javascript";
          script.src = `//www.profitabledisplayformat.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js`;
          conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)}`;

          if (banner.current) {
            banner.current.append(conf);
            banner.current.append(script);
          }
        }
      }, []);
  

  return <div ref={banner} />;
}
```

I'm using AdsTerra to monetize my website, I'm trying to add a multiple banner ads, but if I place this ad component twice on the same page only one shows up am I doing something wrong? or there are some other ways to place it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's a TypeScript implementation for a server-side rendered React application that works with multiple ads of same format (this assumes that you're using different codes for each ad). Also, it's important to note that you *may* need to engage an Adsterra support rep to enable the "JS ASYNC" option if it isn't already enabled in your account (if you see a "JS ASYNC" option when view your respective ad unit code it should be enabled).

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

interface AdsterraProps {
  slot: string;
}

const getId = (slot: string) => `atContainer-${slot}`;

const Adsterra = ({ slot }: AdsterraProps): JSX.Element => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current.firstChild && slot) {
      const atAsyncOptions = {
        key: slot,
        format: 'js',
        async: true,
        container: getId(slot),
        params: {},
      };

      const conf = document.createElement('script');
      conf.innerHTML = `
        if (typeof atAsyncOptions !== 'object') var atAsyncOptions = [];
        atAsyncOptions.push(${JSON.stringify(atAsyncOptions, null, 2)});
      `;
      conf.type = 'text/javascript';

      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.async = true;
      script.src = `//www.your_adcode_domain.com/${slot}/invoke.js`;
      script.type = 'text/javascript';

      if (ref.current) {
        ref.current.append(conf);
        ref.current.append(script);
      }
    }
  }, [slot]);

  return (
    <>
      <div {...{ ref }} />
      <div id={getId(slot)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Adsterra;
```

Also, just fyi this approach deviates slightly from the typical implementation where the script is loaded in the header. If you are not remounting pages on navigation, then you may need to add a route listener and manually invoke `reload`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use same code twice, as detailed [here](https://adsterra.com/blog/how-banner-ads-make-money/), in the "Common mistakes" section :

> 3. The same banner ad code used twice
>
> That’s not a placement mistake, but it can destroy the statistics and
> your CPM. If you need two banners of the same size, you need to
> request two different codes. Please don’t put the same banner twice as
> the stats may work incorrectly. Moreover, these banners will showcase
> the same ads at the same time, frustrating your visitors.

You should create / map a new placement, as detailed [here](https://adsterra.com/blog/how-banner-ads-make-money/), in  "Get Adsterra banner ad codes/scripts" section.

Comment: Oh, I thought otherwise because I talked to customer support and they said it's fine to use it twice, I'll speak to them about that, Thank you

Comment: could you approve my answer ?